# GI or tabular data sources for Global obesity data?

Tags: data, health

I am trying to find either a shp file or some csv, txt etc... showing the %obesity and/or overweight figures broken down per country.
I have checked the [World Health Organisation Data Repository](http://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.home) but I am unable to find any tabular or shp data on there.

Does anybody know of any free resources showing this data at a country level?

Comment: What about this [page](http://www.who.int/gho/ncd/risk_factors/overweight/en/)? There are links to download the data.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Duncan! You are clearly better at navigating the WHO site than I am!

Comment: No I am not, it was Google that found it instantly! All I typed in was "find dan the data he needs"...;-)